# Incompatible delegate type warning

Tags: objective-c, delegates

```
@interface Server : NSObject {
    id<ServerDelegate> _delegate;
    NSInputStream *_inputStream;
    NSOutputStream *_outputStream;
}

@property(nonatomic, assign) id<ServerDelegate> delegate;
```

Whenever I set the delegate of the input or output streams I get a warning that it's assigning to id from incompatible type Server*.

`self.inputStream.delegate = self` is an example of this.

The actual server runs fine it's just the warning that concerns me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to assign `self` (`Server` obejct) as the delegate of `NSInputStream`, your `Server` object must conform to the `NSStreamDelegate` protocol.

Since `NSInputStream` is a subclass of `NSStream`

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSStream_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSStream

```
@interface Server : NSObject<NSStreamDelegate> 
[...]
@end
```

Comment: My `_inputSteam` is a property I just didn't include it in the code I provided

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the `Server` class conform to the NSStreamDelegate:

```
@interface Server : NSObject <NSStreamDelegate> {
    ... var declarations
}
```